# Flutter how to insert a variable in text

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fICQ6.png)

I do as the documentation says, myLevel is a valiable which is equal to 5 but it does not work

Comment: remove `const` from parent, i think it is `Column` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove const on line 35 as myLevel is a dynamic variable

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: please mark useful if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myLevel.toString()` or what you have now. You have the text in a
`children: const [<Widget>, <Widget>, ...]`, you will have to remove the `const` and then add `const` to all the Widgets that turn red.